# Paginating results from union of two tables

Tags: mysql, pagination, sql-order-by, union-all

I have a problem with paginating two large tables:

```
Receipts table: id, receipt_date, record_details (650k records)
Z Reports table: id, receipt_date, record_details (88k records)
```

What I want to do is to sort both of these tables by `receipt_date` and union, after that I want to paginate them. Currently I have this SQL (not exactly but the main idea is this):

```
SELECT c.id, c.receipt_date, c.col_type FROM (
    SELECT a.id, a.receipt_date, 'receipt' AS coltype 
        FROM `terminal_receipts` a
        WHERE `a`.`deleted` IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
        SELECT b.id, b.receipt_date, 'zreport' AS coltype 
        FROM z_reports` b WHERE `b`.`deleted` IS NULL
) c
ORDER BY receipt_date desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

This way, the server selects all records from two tables, orders them by date and then applies the pagination.

But when the row counts increase, this query will take longer to complete. Is there any other algorithm to get the same result without being dependent to table sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a technique called Seek Method, you can read about [here](https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/). According to it, you need to identify a set of columns that uniquely identifies each row. This set of column will then be used with a predicate when searching through the database.

The link I mentioned has some examples, but here's another one, a very simple one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rev` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`rev`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', '1', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('1', '2', 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('1', '3', 'The earth is like a ball.');

SELECT *
FROM `docs`
ORDER BY rev, id
LIMIT 2;


SELECT * 
FROM `docs`
WHERE (rev, id) > (1, 2) # let's use the last row from the previous select with the predicate
ORDER BY rev, id
LIMIT 2;

SELECT * 
FROM `docs`
WHERE (rev, id) > (3, 1) # same idea
ORDER BY rev, id
LIMIT 2;
```

[SQLFiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/91897)

Having indexes will further speed up pagination.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the ordering is based to date&time and there are two tables, that doesn't help me much either. for example, if I index them, it can be `z1 r1 r2 r3 z2 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 z3` etc and I would need two markers.